# Shell Script on removing file that is not accessed for 2 weeks

Tags: shell, centos

I got a queston on shell command

```
rm -rf
```

I am trying to find files that have not been accessed for e.g 14 days and I would like to remove it, but how do I add to my command so I can find and remove such file.

I am using CentOS 6

Comment: Try to perform a bit of search.  You should be able to find several (if not numerous) examples of this on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just throwing some general direction in there:

I would do a loop.
if the file is older than 14 days
rm -rf
end-if

For the date of the file, you can use the current date, minus 14 days... and I would go with UNIX time.

But yes, as devnull answered, you have to search more.
Google is your friend.
There's probably a bunch of stuff in StackOverflow, and a whole lot more in google.